# Rotate text 90 degrees in a VBA button

Tags: forms, vba, excel, button

How do I rotate text inside a button, textbox, etc. by a given amount inside a [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) form sheet?

Comment: No built in way.  The best you can do is create your button and create a narrow label (workwrap=True) and layer that label onto your button.

Comment: Userform, or workheet ? ("form sheet" isn't a term I recognize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly in VBA, but you can still accomplish a similar visual effect with the buttons (sorry, the textbox is impossible) by using a 3rd party BMP editor.

1. Create a rotated image with the given text that you want to have.  Make sure to use the same font family, style, & size (Tahoma, regular, 8pt by default) and set the background color of the image to the system palette background color, which is RGB(240,240,240) or hex #F0F0F0.  Also make sure the height and width of the image is roughly the same size as the button you want to rotate.
2. Save the rotated image as a bitmap (.bmp) file.
3. In the **Properties** box of the *CommandButton1*, scroll down to the *Picture* property, click the ellipses on the right, navigate to and select the rotated image.

### Final Result

[image]

### Edit 1: Another Option

This next part is mainly a proof-of-concept and is by no means a complete solution.  You will need to find the correct customized .ttf or .otf font file and then install it on all the systems you want to use the rotated text on.

Depending on how complicated you want to get, you can actually create a monospaced font where each character is rotated 90° and then use VBA code to insert/delete characters at the proper location.

I used *Vertigo* from http://www.1001fonts.com/vertigo-font.html which was the only TrueType font I could find without either putting in effort to create my own or paying for it.  The one big problem I see with this font is that it is not monospaced and that the height of each character (say for example, underscore _) is not consistent, so you cannot properly add spaces or underscores (a major downside I realize, so you will need to find/create your own font).

To install the font on a Windows system:

1. Simply unzip the file anywhere you'd like
2. Double click the file you want; you will see the waterfall layout of the font family to ensure you're installing the correct font file
3. Click the Install button at the top
4. Restart your computer

Then, on the TextBox1's property menu, scroll to Font, click the <kbd>...</kbd> and select **Vertigo** as the font family.  Also, set MultiLine to true.  You will need to make sure the width of the textbox is small enough that only 1 character can fit on a line and tall enough to fit your entire word.

The result looks something like this:

[image]

I realized with this font that the letters were coming in backwards, so I had to add a little basic code on the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events to properly handle basic typing (ignores where the blinker is at and only deals with the most recent character at the end)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Chr(KeyAscii) & Me.TextBox1.Value
    KeyAscii = False
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 8 Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Mid(Me.TextBox1.Value, 2, Len(Me.TextBox1.Value))
        KeyCode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome 

Cheers Michael